# Theming Subpages

Tags: theming, nodes, 7

Back in Drupal 6, if I wanted to create a sub-theme for a bunch of pages, I could make a special pages-subtheme.tpl.php page and this would handle not only the /subtheme page, but also /subtheme/page1, /subtheme/page2, /subtheme/sub-subpage/page3 etc...

With the changes to Drupal 7, I could be wrong, but it looks like I have to do this node by node.  And it also looks like I can't use the pathauto paths...

Thus those same 3 nodes which in Drupal 6 were pages-subtheme.tpl.php become in Drupal 7 three distinctly themed pages--node--40.tpl.php, pages--node--57.tpl.php, pages--node--23.tpl.php etc...

I'm hoping I'm wrong about this, which is why I'm asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it help you to create a tpl.php page based on the node itself or by content-type? For example, you'd have your main page.tpl.php, but then for specific content types (subtheme), you'd have a page--content-type.tpl.php or node--type.tpl.php.

If you plan the sitemap and templates carefully beforehand you should be able to avoid creating individual page--node--1.tpl.php, etc.

Check out: https://drupal.org/node/1089656 (Drupal Theme Hook Suggestions)

The hook suggestions normally require a template_page_preprocess() function, but once you have it set up you're good to go.

I think you're right about pathauto paths not working for .tpl.php names, but you might be able to write your own preprocess function to accommodate those.